# Custom dutch bike project

Tags: stem, steerer, customization

Here I am a Kiwi in the Netherlands with a little dutch bike project underway.

The internal of the steerer tube is 19.3mm (give or take) so I am unable to put a 1" - 1" 1/4 (32mm Handlebar diameter) stem adapter into the steerer tube.

I think my best bet is to find a stem to bolt on the 22mm (outside diameter) to 32mm handlebar. (Maybe a shim in needed.)

Any suggestions and help with companies or suppliers making this product would be much appreciated.

p.s Welder/Fabricator fitter turner by trade but living in a different company not working in my field very unfortunitly.

Steerer dimensions.

- Inside diameter: 19mm
- Outside diameter: 22mm
- Handlebar dimension: 32mm
- Part needed = 22mm-32mm stem.

Much appreciated guys.

Comment: What's your exact question -ie, what are you asking?  How to fit a non-standard sized stem around a steerer?   But you're talking about the ID of the steerer tube not the OD, which makes me wonder if you're fitting an old style quill stem into a modern threadless steerer.   Adding a photo of your parts and what doesn't fit, could be of benefit to the question.

Comment: I am in need or a stem with odd size's. |
It need to fit onto the steerer with OD of 22mm/0.87in and handle bars 32mm/tungsten carbide cutters.
I am not sure its possible to get a quill stem for the internal measurement of the steerer which is 19mm.

I can upload photos tomorrow if this is to hard to image :D

Comment: OK - the 31.8mm OD of your bar's clamp area is a modern standard.  That's fine.
But I cannot find a steerer OD near 22 mm. Photos would be helpful please.  I'm guessing its a smaller/older kid's fork being mated to a modern handlebar, and have a vague suspicion that a quill-to-threadless adapter may appear in the final answer.  This is a great question btw.

Comment: Correct mate!
The handle bar end is the easy part, The steerer not so easy!!
Its a very old dutch bike probably from the 50s/60s and ya was given modern straight bars.
Im also thinking about over sised + shim...

Yeah i dont think to many people play around with bikes here. Bikes are just bikes for them and its cheaper just to buy one ect but im a practical kiwi who loves a project and its find of based of the idea of a fixie but not hahaha. strip the bike,remove excess brackets ect,paint and custom.

Comment: more photos please?  Question risks being closed without further info.

Comment: Over a week old - please add photos, which will submit the question to the Reopen queue.